# TailwindCSS custom classes and gradients not working on Vercel

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vercel

My custom Tailwindclasses and gradients are not being shown when deploying on Vercel, while they work perfectly on localhost (both dev and production). I am using Nuxt 2 with the latest TailwindCSS (3.3.2) being installed as a plugin.

This is how my nuxt.config.js looks like:

```
css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css']

 build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        'tailwindcss',
        'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
        [
          'postcss-preset-env',
          {
            autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
            features: {
              'custom-properties': false,
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    }
  }
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
    content: [
      './components/**/*.{vue,js}',
      './layouts/**/*.vue',
      './pages/**/*.vue',
      './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
      './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
      './assets/**/*.{vue,js}',
      './assets/css/*.css'
    ],
  safelist: ['text-gradient-warm', 'btn-gradient', 'btn-gradient:hover', 'bg-gradient-to-r', 'from-[#44BCFF]', 'via-[#FF44EC]', 'to-[#FF675E]'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'blue-custom': '#44BCFF',
        'pink-custom': '#FF44EC',
        'orange-custom': '#FF675E'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('daisyui'),
  ],
  daisyui: {
    styled: true,
    themes: ["light"],
  },
}
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'tailwindcss',
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
    [
      'postcss-preset-env',
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: 'no-2009',
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          'custom-properties': false,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

I have tried so many things but it just does not seem to work. I have also tried all solutions for similar problems I have found online but does not seem to be doing anything. Most text-gradients do not work, and most importantly, some gradient backgrounds on button do not work. For example:

```
<div class="absolute transition-all duration-1000 opacity-60 -inset-px bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-custom via-pink-custom to-orange-custom rounded-xl blur-lg group-hover:opacity-80 group-hover:-inset-1 group-hover:duration-200 animate-tilt"></div>
```

Shows a nice gradient shadow underneath my button but it shows nothing once deployed on Vercel.

I just made a public repo that can be cloned: https://github.com/fdarkaou/tailwindvercel

You can all install dependencies using `yarn install`, and I am using `nuxt generate` as the build command.

You can see the difference between localhost and deployment on vercel here:

Vercel: https://pasteboard.co/ZBnG3n5BhWO8.png
Localhost: https://pasteboard.co/573VNtLDE9rQ.png

As you can see, the gradient is not showing up on Vercel.

I have tried: safelisting content, editing nuxt.config.js, postcss.config.js, tailwindcss.config.js.

Comment: It seems like when deploying, some CSS variable "defaults" from Tailwind are being stripped, in particular, ` --tw-gradient-from-position: ;  --tw-gradient-via-position: ;  --tw-gradient-to-position: ;`